# A CTEX problem, a package is not recognized

Tags: ctex

The red dot in the picture below says: Package fontspec Error: The font "KaiTi" cannot be found.

I think the problem is from the package ctex, and some commands are not recognized.

[image]

Comment: look at the overleap help menu, they list all the fonts they have installed

Comment: Check this [link](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/Which_OTF_or_TTF_fonts_are_supported_via_fontspec%3F#Chinese).